# Serial downvoting not reversed?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Recently I've gotten downvotes in quick succession (within the same minute) across two days, even including a community wiki self Q&A:

[image]

And it looks like they've just downvoted my most recent answers (they're from a while ago, not terribly active here anymore):

[image]

Should I worry about this/does this qualify as serial voting even though it hasn't been reversed yet?

Comment: Have you waited 24 hours before posting this?

Comment: @SamuelLiew My bad, I did not for the top 3 which were just reversed. But the bottom 4 from 2 days ago have not. I thought it was an anomaly but the second wave made me suspicious.